# How to handle SendFailedException?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to send bulk email.
I am using ItemReader to fetch list with details to whom emails needs to be send and preparing it with ItemProcessor and sending it with ItemWriter.
It Works fine but problem is I have to identify that for which email id mail sending failed.

In short I want to do something like this :

```
        try { 
            mailSender.send(items.toArray(new MimeMessagePreparator[items.size()])); 
        } catch (final SendFailedException e) { 
            logProblem(e); 

            final Address[] invalidAddresses = e.getInvalidAddresses(); 
            setFailedAddresses(invalidAddresses); 
            final Address[] validSentAddresses = e.getValidSentAddresses(); 
            setConfirmedAddresses(validSentAddresses); 
            final Address[] validUnsentAddresses = e.getValidUnsentAddresses(); 
            resend(validUnsentAddresses); 
        }
```

but send method definition is like this

**JavaMailSender.send(MimeMessagePreparator[] arg0) throws MailException**

so it shows unreachable catch block

Here is my ItemProcessor implementation :

```
@Override
    public MimeMessagePreparator process(final UserEmailDtlBO userEmailDtlBO) throws Exception {

       MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
           public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
             MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,true);
             message.setTo(userEmailDtlBO.getEmail());
             message.setFrom(mailbundle.getString("mailFrom"));
             Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             model.put("user", userEmailDtlBO);
            // message.addInline("logoImg", new ClassPathResource("/conf/logo_green.png"));
             String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "/conf/demo_email.vm", "utf-8", model);
             message.setSubject("demo email template");
             message.setText(text, true);
             URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/conf/logo_green.png");
             String fileStr = resource.getFile();
             File emailLogo = new File(fileStr);
             message.addInline("logoImg", emailLogo);
           }};
    return preparator;
    }
```

here is my ItemWriter implementation :

```
@Override
    public void write(List<? extends MimeMessagePreparator> items) throws MailException{
        mailSender.send(items.toArray(new MimeMessagePreparator[items.size()]));
    }
```

Please help me in handling SendFailedException .

Comment: Do any of the "get cause" methods on MailException return the original JavaMail MessagingException, of which SendFailedException is a subclass?

Comment: No it doesn't thorows any exception for wrong email id.@BillShannon

Comment: Ah, I see you're asking how to identify that the address is bad, not just how to handle the exception in the cases where the server tells you it's bad.  As the [JavaMail FAQ explains](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr), the server can't always tells you that an address is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException
```

is a checked exception, so

```
org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender.send(MimeMessagePreparator... mimeMessagePreparators)
```

will never throw a checked exception, only the runtime exceptions as defined in javadoc API.

You can check, if the thrown exception is of type

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException
```

, and then call

```
ex.getFailedMessages()
```

on those exception. At least org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl is filling the failed messages under specific conditions (check sourcecode for details).
If not, write your own impl class catching the SendFailedException, extract the desired values and wrap it in your own MySendFailedException.

For handling in Spring Batch, you can define a

```
org.springframework.batch.core.ItemWriteListener
```

and handle the exception in

```
public void onWriteError(Exception ex, List<? extends O> item) {    }
```